# User ID's returned from Tweepy are huge numbers that don't link to any accounts

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, tweets, userid

I have been downloading tonnes of tweets for the last few weeks. In order to reduce download time, I only saved tweet user ids not the user account. I need to pass them through a bot check but have now realised that 90% of the user ids are huge numbers (e.g. 1.25103113308656E+018) and cannot be used to search for the account.

Is there a way to convert these back to an account number?

Notes:

- The tweet_id column is an equally huge, different number meaning they haven't been read into the wrong column.
- When I raise them from the e notation into their raw number it still doesn't work.

I am limited by the week window of the twitter api so I must find a way of linking the data I have already got to individual accounts. This work is for a charitable cause and your help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The Tweepy API call returns a Response which contains the data in the **_json** field. You can parse the **user** key of the said json and extract the IDs and the **screen name** of the user and store it. 
Then you can query the Tweepy api again as per their [doc](http://docs.tweepy.org/en/latest/api.html#user-methods) to get the user information.

Please make a note that when you store the ID field, you have to cast it to the String datatype.

Comment: Very useful! Thank you so much.